# React build with env file from a command line

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-build

Is there any way to create React App build from a command like? So far I have in the shell script:

```
npm install;
npm run-script build:test;
```

where `build:test` is

```
bash -ac '. .env.test; react-scripts build'
```

but that will refer to `build:test` script from `package.json` but when I want to use specific `.env` file in the shell script (without editing or adding anything to `package.json`) as follow

```
npm run .env.my_box react-scripts build;
```

that will not execute build for `.env.my_box`

What I have set incorrectly?

Comment: I'm curious why you would store the various env configs along side each other vs having your .env file created in the stage you're at. 

IE: in circle-ci the automated builder I use, I inject the env variables into the container at each stage vs checking something like that in.  Would that work for you?

Comment: @Petrogad we are using Ansible for CD

Answer (score 0):

you should try this library https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd

Update your package.json

```
   "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject",
   "build:stage": "env-cmd -f ./.env.stage npm run-script build" 
}
```

then `npm run build:stage`

Comment: But this is the same I have above. Question is if I can use `env-cmd -f ./.env.stage npm run-script build` from the command like or shell script

Comment: Apparently `npm run env-cmd -f ./.env.stage npm run-script build` from a command line is no working

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

on package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "cd server && npm start",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "server-dep": "cd server && npm install",
    "client-dep": "cd client && npm install",
    "install-dep": "npm install && concurrently \"npm run server-dep\" \"npm run client-dep\"",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

then npm run start for example, this is monorepo so we run server and frontend with one command

Comment: I'm trying to automate build. That solution is not going to work from a command line when need to pass `.env` file to the automation script